# If dos a single function solidity, will other functions not work?

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, denial-of-service, dos

I read lots of articles about dos causing a Denial Of Service.

Let say that a contract has 2 functions, if called one of them repeatedly, will the other function works?

```
Contract ABC {

function one() external{
   // code logic
  }
function two() external{
   // code logic
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in normal mode, the performance of two functions is separate and has nothing to do with each other unless the second function is affected by the attacked function. Dos attack in blockchain does not mean consecutive calls In fact, it is creating a malfunction in the performance of the function, for example, creating a condition where the required gas consumption function is more than the allowed limit and will never be executed again and will always be rejected.

Comment: I see, but it's possible to call a function constantly, thus not allowing other users to call that function?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by DoS. For your knowledge dos = Denial of Service.

In fact, on Ethereum, there are many ways to DoS a function.
For example, in this smart contract :

```
Contract ABC {
address maliciousContract;

function vulnerablefunction() external external {

   result = maliciousContract.maliciousFunction();
   require(result);

   // code logic
  }

}
```

If a user succeed to add the address of a contract that return `false` for each call of `maliciousFunction()`, and that the address can't be modified after that, this is a DoS attack.
Then, we call DoS any unwanted behavior which causes the revert of new transactions.

In Ethereum, you can't do DoS by calling a function with many computers for one simple reason: you have to pay gas for each transactions. So if you are very rich, you pass every new transaction during one block but not during one day long.

Moreover, in the case you can do it, you will not stop a specific contract but all transactions. Imagine that Ethereum is one big server (the EVM). Each transaction is executed one by one because it changes the global state of the EVM.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how DoS works in the context of smart contracts. You DoS a contract or a function by making it always revert or unable to compete properly by exploiting a loophole in its code (such as making a condition permanently false, making a call to the function require too much gas... cf Coriolan's answer). Repeatedly calling a function hoping to cause some sort of "contract overload" doesnt work, because ethereum isnt built a way that could make that possible. Spamming could halt the whole chain, but not a specific contract.